NextJS SEO with Client and Server components
I want to add a page to my website like /my-website/courses/course-1. I'm wondering how could I render the content of that course-1 to make it seo friendly. Currently I have the following component:
'use client';

import { useBoughtCourse, useBuyCourse } from '@/api/course/hooks';
import { useCurrentUser } from '@/api/user/hooks';
import { CourseTree } from '@/app/courses/[name]/tree/course-tree';
import { CourseReviews } from '@/app/courses/course-reviews';
import { VideoPlayer } from '@/components/player/video-player';
import { ReviewsSummary } from '@/components/reviews';
import { RichHtml } from '@/components/rich-html';
import { TargetBadges } from '@/components/target-badges';
import { Button } from '@/components/ui/button';
import { TextGradient } from '@/components/ui/text-gradient';
import { UserCard } from '@/components/user-card';
import { formatDate, msToShortTime, sum } from '@/lib/utils';
import { Course } from '@/types';
import { UseQueryResult } from '@tanstack/react-query';
import { Newspaper, Paperclip, PlaySquare, RefreshCcw } from 'lucide-react';
import Link from 'next/link';
import { usePathname } from 'next/navigation';
import { GiTwoCoins } from 'react-icons/gi';

export const CourseLandingPage = ({
  queryCourse,
}: {
  queryCourse: UseQueryResult<Course>;
}) => {
  const queryCurrentUser = useCurrentUser();
  const pathname = usePathname();

  console.log('USER', queryCurrentUser.data);

  const queryBoughtCourse = useBoughtCourse(
    { id: queryCourse.data?.id! },
    !!queryCurrentUser.data
  );
  const mutationBuyCourse = useBuyCourse({ id: queryCourse.data?.id! });

  if (queryBoughtCourse.isLoading || queryCourse.isLoading || !queryCourse.data)
    return null;

  const course = queryCourse.data!;

  const BuySection = () => {
    return (
      <div className='sticky right-[100px] top-[100px] z-[10] flex w-[30rem] flex-col gap-5'>
        <div className='w-[20rem] rounded-md border-[2px] border-dashed bg-card p-3'>
          {course.marketingVideo && (
            <VideoPlayer src={course.marketingVideo.url} />
          )}
          {queryCurrentUser.data?.role === 'TEACHER' ||
          course.author.id ===
            queryCurrentUser.data?.id ? null : queryBoughtCourse.data ? (
            <div className='my-3 w-full'>
              <p>
                Ten kurs został zakupiony dnia{' '}
                {formatDate(new Date(queryBoughtCourse.data.createdAt), 'PPP')}.
              </p>
              <Link href={`${pathname}/learn`} className='w-full'>
                <Button gradient gradientClassName='w-fit'>
                  Przejdź do kursu
                </Button>
              </Link>
            </div>
          ) : (
            <button
              className='my-3 flex w-full cursor-default items-center justify-center gap-2 rounded-full border border-dashed bg-background p-2 text-xl shadow-none hover:bg-muted'
              disabled={queryBoughtCourse.isLoading}
              onClick={() => mutationBuyCourse.mutate(queryCourse.data.id)}
            >
              <div className='flex items-center justify-center gap-1.5'>
                <GiTwoCoins className='h-6 w-6 fill-gold-10' />
                {course.price}
              </div>
              <span className=''>Kup</span>
            </button>
          )}
          <p className='pb-2 text-lg font-semibold'>
            <TextGradient color='brand'>Zawartość kursu</TextGradient>
          </p>
          <div className='flex flex-col items-start gap-2'>
            <span className='flex items-center justify-center gap-2'>
              <PlaySquare /> Treści video:{' '}
              <span>{msToShortTime(course.duration * 1000)}</span>
            </span>
            <span className='flex items-center justify-center gap-2'>
              <Newspaper /> <span>Artykuły: {course.articlesCount}</span>
            </span>{' '}
            <span className='flex items-center justify-center gap-2'>
              <Paperclip />{' '}
              <span>
                Załączniki:{' '}
                {sum(
                  course.content.map((item) => item.attachments?.length || 0)
                )}
              </span>
            </span>{' '}
            {/* <span className='flex items-center justify-center gap-2'>
              <InfinityIcon /> <span>Dożywotni dostęp</span>
            </span> */}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  };

  return (
    <div className='flex gap-10'>
      <div className='flex max-w-[700px] flex-1 flex-col justify-start gap-2'>
        <h1 className='text-3xl font-bold'>
          <TextGradient color='secondary'>{course.name}</TextGradient>
        </h1>
        <RichHtml html={course.description} />
        <div className='flex items-center gap-2'>
          <ReviewsSummary
            count={course.ratingsCount}
            rating={course.ratingsAvg}
          />
          <span className='text-sm'>
            {queryCourse.data.boughtCoursesCount} uczestników
          </span>
        </div>
        <p className='flex items-center justify-center gap-1.5 self-start text-sm'>
          <RefreshCcw className='h-4 w-4' /> Ostatnia aktualizacja:{' '}
          <span>{formatDate(new Date(course.updatedAt), 'PPP pp')}</span>
        </p>
        <UserCard user={course.author} />

        <div className='mt-10'>
          <h3 className='text-2xl font-bold'>Opis</h3>
          <RichHtml html={course.description} />
        </div>

        <div className='mt-10 flex flex-col gap-2 '>
          <h3 className='text-2xl font-bold'>Zawartość</h3>
          <CourseTree queryCourse={queryCourse} type='landing-page' />
        </div>

        <div className='flex flex-wrap items-end gap-1'>
          <TargetBadges
            domains={course.domains}
            theorems={course.theorems}
            definitions={course.definitions}
            tags={course.tags}
          />
        </div>
        <CourseReviews course={course} />
      </div>
      <BuySection />
    </div>
  );
};


Its entirely client site rendered so I guess I would need to move some parts like course description into server component? And is that OK to nest client components into server ones and vice versa like Page is a server component, the CourseLandingPage is client ones but inside of it I can make CourseDescription component that is server side rendered and it works for SEO. DO I understand it correctly?

I actually just ran into this with a NextJS project. Google was not able to crawl any of the content in the client components, so you'll want to make sure that anything important for SEO is server-rendered.

And I can't be nested inside client component?

When something is client-side rendered with "use client", that just means the server sends the js to the client to run, so that things like hooks, state, and other interactive elements will function. Next.js will still attempt to fill the page with as much content as it can that isn't dynamically generated by your javascript, so if you mark static content with "use client" it can still show up for crawlers.
If we use the example of the stock html <button/>, if you put it in a client component, the initial render will show that button on the page. However, clicking the button will do nothing until next.js hydrates the page and hooks the javascript up to the button. Therefore, if something would only appear on the page after you click that button, it will not contribute to your SEO.
In addition, you're correct that you can nest a client component within a server component. However, it's important to note that you cannot nest server components within client components. Once you have a client component, that component and every component beneath it in the component tree will be a client component, regardless of whether you mark it with "use client".
My recommendation would be to figure out exactly what parts of your page require client-side rendering, and isolate them in their own client components. Nest those components where needed in your page, you should try to server-render as much as possible. If you have to, you can inject server-rendered content into a client component, but this is a more advanced pattern that you likely don't need here.
Overall you're on the right track, I'd recommend continuing to read up on how next.js works. Try this tutorial series on YouTube, I think it's pretty thorough and useful.
